# Flex: When text too long break into new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I was thinking if it is possible to achieve following using css **flexbox**.

In the layout, there are originaly 2 div next to each other. Left one contains group of icons and has a fixed width. Right one contains text, which can be potentially quite long.

Is there a way, how to make using **only css (especially flexbox)**, that when the text is too long, the div will break onto the new line (under first div)?

Check the following image.
[image]

Comment: Do you really need a flexbox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by creating a container with `display: flex;`, and `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Then give the overflow text a `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixed-width {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fixed-width,
.overflow-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.overflow-text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-width">
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="overflow-text"><p>This is some text that is really long.</p></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y33Lwwvm/5/)