# How to set text in a way that it starts a new line automatically after reaching limit

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this using flexbox where the icon and text are set with flex row property, but what i want to do is basically getting the full email without extending the border limit. I tried with flexbox wrap property but that doesn't apply here since its a single p tag.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flex: When text too long break into new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930217/flex-when-text-too-long-break-into-new-line)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
    white-space:nowrap;

But if there is not enough space, the email address whill necessarily go out of the box :-(

[A simulator to test the result of white-space](http://stylescss.free.fr/v2-properties/white-space.php#simulateur).